# How to prove that the current generated by a battery would be the same that would return to it from negative terminal?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, batteries

How could we prove that in a complex circuit with more than 1 battery the current which would be emitted by one battery would be the same which would return to its negative terminal by knowing that current splits itself ?

Comment: Prove mathematically? Or prove experimentally?

Comment: Explain the reason why we consider that in a complex circuit with more than 1 battery the current that any one battery would supply would be the same returning to it.

Answer (score 1):

It is an assumption. We assume that there is no accumulation of charge anywhere in the circuit wires(if there were, the resulting electric fields would nullify it in sometime anyway). Then, must follow from conservation of charge that whatever's being pumped out, comes back in. The key point is this is a steady-state situation; a current has been set up and all the initial turbulence has been given enough time to settle down..